# are header guards limited to the scope of their respective library?

Tags: c, struct, header

I've inherited some code* which declares and defines a struct in a header file (a_A.h). This struct is in the top file of an include hierarchy tree which symbolically looks like:

```
 file: t_T.h (#includes "c_C.h") //defines a struct
 file: c_C.h (#includes "h_H.h")
 file: h_H.h (#includes "a_C.h")
 file: a_C.h (#includes <stdio.h>)
```

Each header has the appropriate header guards and appear to be non-recursive when looked at as a flat collection of files. However, files c_C.h and a_C.h reside in the same library. While h_H.h resides in a different library. From a library perspective this symbolically appears as:

```
t_T.h (includes a file from Lib_C) 
Lib_C: (includes a file from Lib_H)
Lib_H (includes a file from Lib_C)
```

which is recursive and is the likely cause of redefinition problems when I compile the code (the linker complains that the struct in file a_C.h is redefined).

1) Did I correctly identify the issue?

2) If so, why? I am guessing that linked objects in a library appear flat to the linker (i.e. they've lost their hierarchy context). And if guessed somewhat  correctly then:

3) Should I consider header guards to be limited to the scope of their respective library?

Below is the error statement from the problems window:

```
symbol "ov5642_1280x960_RAW" redefined: first defined in "./TakePhoto.obj"; redefined in "./ArduCam/ov5642_Config.obj"
```

Header in ./TakePhoto:

```
#ifndef TAKEPHOTO_H
#define TAKEPHOTO_H
#include "ov5642_Config.h"
#include "HAL_ArduCAM.h"
...
#endif /* TAKEPHOTO_H_ */
```

Header in ./ArduCAM/ov5642_Config.h:

```
#ifndef ARDUCAM_OV5642_CONFIG_H_
#define ARDUCAM_OV5642_CONFIG_H_
#include "HAL_ArduCAM.h"
#include "ov5642_Sensor_Values.h"
....
#endif /* ARDUCAM_OV5642_CONFIG_H_ */
```

Header in HAL_ArduCAM

```
#ifndef  HAL_ArduCAM_h
#define  HAL_ArduCAM_h
#include <stdint.h>
#include "driverlib.h"
....
#endif /* HAL_ArduCAM_h */
```

ov5642_Sensor_Values.h has the following

```
#ifndef ARDUCAM_OV5642_SENSOR_VALUES_H_
#define ARDUCAM_OV5642_SENSOR_VALUES_H_
#include <stdint.h>
const struct sensor_reg ov5642_1280x960_RAW[] =
{
     {0x3103,0x93},
     {0x3008,0x02},
     {0x3017,0x7f},
 .....

#endif /* ARDUCAM_OV5642_SENSOR_VALUES_H_ */
```

It seems that the contents of OV5642_Sensor_Values is copied twice, once for TakePhoto and once again for ovV5642_Config despite their header guards. My original thought was that there was a recursive dependencies but didn't find it.

Ok, I've made an example pasted below. There are five files in this example, three files (bar.h, foo.h, foo.c reside in a library), the other two files (foo1.h, foo1.c) do not. Notice that foo.h includes bar.h and that foo1 includes both foo.h and bar.h.

I am conjecturing that the guard headers of bar.h are not preserved when the pre-processor copies into foo.h. Thus when foo1 includes bar.h and foo.h the symbol redefinition arises.  So to answer my own question, no, it is not a library issue. Not preserving the header guard seems the likely cause of my problem.

They are pasted below.

```css
/*
 * bar.h
 *
 */

#ifndef ARDUCAM_BAR_H_
#define ARDUCAM_BAR_H_
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct regStruct {
     uint16_t reg;
     uint8_t val;
 } regStruct;

 const struct regStruct regArray[] =
  {
      {0x3103,0x03},
      {0x3104,0x03},
      {0x3008,0x82},
      {0xffff,0xff},
  };
 const struct regStruct tinyArray[] =
   {
       {0x3106,0x03},
       {0x3003,0x82},
       {0xffff,0xff},
   };

#endif /* ARDUCAM_BAR_H_ */
```

```css
/*
 * foo.h
 *
 *
 */

#ifndef ARDUCAM_FOO_H_
#define ARDUCAM_FOO_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h" //including this file causes redefinition


typedef struct Init_Parameters {
    //! Select sensor resolution
    //! options.
    //! \n Valid values are:
    //! - \b big
    //! - \b small
    //! - \b tiny
    uint8_t size;

} Init_Parameters;


uint8_t Sensor_Init(Init_Parameters *param);

typedef enum {
    small=0,
    big,
    tiny
} select_size;

#endif /* ARDUCAM_FOO_H_ */
```

```css
/*
 * foo.c
 *
 *
 */

#include "foo.h"

uint8_t Sensor_Init(Init_Parameters *param)
{
    switch(param->size)
    {
    case big:
        break;
    case  small:
        break;
    case  tiny:
        break;
    }
    return 0x01;
}
```

```css
/*
 * foo1.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 28, 2019
 *      Author: jnadi
 */

#ifndef FOO1_H_
#define FOO1_H_

#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

#endif /* FOO1_H_ */
```

```css
/*
 * foo1.c
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 28, 2019
 *      Author: jnadi
 */

#include "foo1.h"

void Camera_Init(){

    Init_Parameters setParams; //create instance
    setParams.size=big;
    Sensor_Init(&setParams);

}
```

Comment: Can you please post [mcve]? Like the minimal content of all of the files mentioned which is reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am under pressure to get this code working and am currently in the process of restructuring the code to avoid the recursive library issues. It will take awhile before I can do so. I had hoped that my description would suffice

Comment: What do you mean by "files c_C.h and a_C.h reside in the same library"?  Header files may declare functions and those function definitions may come from a particular library, and perhaps that's what you mean.  But the use of the word "reside" seems to imply that you misunderstand the relationship between header files and libraries.  In particular, I have no idea what "t_T.h (includes a file from Lib_C)" means.  You cannot include a file from a library, although you can include a file which may come from the source tree used to build a library.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the __complete and unedited__ error message from the linker.  I think you have misunderstood what it means and, because of this, are looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: Hello zwoi. I added the messages from the linker. I really hope I misunderstood the error. I also added the header files which include the file holding the redefined "ov5642_1280x960_RAW" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The physical locations of header files affect C source compilation only via the include-file search path.  Headers have to be in one of the directories that are searched, and if there is more than one with the same name, then the search path order determines which is used.  The association, if any, between a given header and a library is not known to the compiler, and it does not affect compilation, unless indirectly via the search path.

Your claim that

> **the linker** complains that the struct in file a_C.h is redefined

(emphasis added) makes sense only if by "the struct" you mean an *object* of a structure type.  The linker may complain if a variable with external linkage is defined in more than one translation unit, which will likely happen if a header contains a definition of that variable (as opposed to merely a declaration).

If instead the issue is that the structure *type* is redefined, then that would be diagnosed by the compiler, not the linker, and it would tend to contradict your conclusion that

> Each header has the appropriate header guards

.  Proper header guards are exactly what would prevent such a type redefinition issue.

> 1) Did I correctly identify the issue?

Not with any specificity, for sure.  That there are header dependencies in both directions between headers associated with different libraries reflects poor design, but it would not inherently cause compilation or linking to fail.

> 2) If so [...]

N/A

> 3) Should I consider header guards to be limited to the scope of their
>   respective library?

No.  Header guards are relevant at the compilation stage only, and C compilation knows nothing about libraries.  All header files processed by the compiler in the course of translating a single translation unit are on equal footing.  In fact, the main risk in this area is in the opposite direction: a collision of header guards.

---

That answers the question as posed.  As for what the true nature of your build issue may be, you have not given us enough information to do more than speculate.  My own speculations are already conveyed above.

Comment: I agree with your observation that it is poor design for libraries to have header dependencies on each other.  I am restructuring the code. the search paths are correct -translations units compile without problem. I've double checked the header guards, they are correct. The type struct is both declared and defined in only one header file.  the linker complains that the redefinition occurs in two different translation units which would seems to be a header guard issue. I will follow your suggestion and go to the physical location of the files to check for duplicate file names.

Comment: Do consider the possibility that you don't have the kind of cross-library header dependency you think you have.  If, again, yours is a compiler error about redefinition of a structure *type*, then it may be that you have a genuine redefinition.  The type itself or the whole header may have been copied, though if it's the whole header then its include guards would need to have been modified in one place or the other, too.

Comment: The struct type is defined and declared in only one header file with correct header guards. But it does appear that the header is included twice somehow which is why I thought that the clumsy inter library dependency copied the header twice, once for each library (probably wrong as you suggested). I am moving the code around to remove the cross library dependencies to see if it makes a difference (not a good engineering approach). Regardless of the outcome, I would like to thank you for your time and consideration. You certainly have brought up points for me to think about.

Comment: Hi John, I added the error message and the header guards used in the two header files for reference. Hopefully I screwed up something in the header guard

Answer (score 0):

Using the five files posted above and commenting out an **#includes bar.h** in foo.h, I believe I found the answer to my problem.

The simple answer is that header guards are not preserved once it is included into the header of another file.

When bar.h is included into another header file, its header guards are superseded by the header guards of its new host (foo.h). Thus symbol redefinition issues arise when foo1.h includes both bar.h and foo.h

Comment: You are right: it's a linker error.  Thus, as I said, it's about multiple definitions of an *object*.  It is not the header guards are somehow lost when one header is included into another.  They are not.  The issue is that two *different translation units* both acquire definitions of the same object from the header.  In fact, the header defines two objects: arrays `regArray` and `tinyArray`.  The presence of those definitions in the header is your root problem.  The header may *declare* those, but their definitions should be in just one translation unit of any given program.

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative, but it's not what *I* would call a dependency.  I would just call it a flawed header.  It is inappropriate for a header to define an object with external linkage, because undefined behavior then results from including that header in two different translation units contributing to the same program. So what was the point of the external linkage?  It's also usually inappropriate for a header to define an object with *internal* linkage, but at least that does not produce UB.

Answer (score 0):

Header guards only prevent a `.h` file from including its contents twice or more within *one* top-level translation unit.  They are to deal with cases like this, where two or more headers need to include the same set of common definitions:

```
// A.h
struct A { int x, y, z; };

// B.h
#include "A.h"
struct B { struct A aye; float f, g; };

// C.h
#include "A.h"
struct C { struct A aye; long l, m; };

// main.c
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h" // error, redefinition of struct A
```

But each translation unit starts out with a clean macro environment, so if you include a header file in two different top-level translation units, that header's declarations are made visible (once) to each.  And that's what you want.  (Think about standard library headers.  You wouldn't want `stdio.h` not to declare `printf` in `bar.c` just because there existed `foo.c` in the same project that also included `stdio.h`.)

Now, your problem is that `ov5642_Sensor_Values.h` defines a *data object* (not a type), `ov5642_1280x960_RAW`, and this header is included into two different top-level translation units (`.c` source files).  Each translation unit produces an object file containing a definition of `ov5642_1280x960_RAW`, and you get a multiple definition error from the linker when you try to combine them.

The bug causing this problem is not that `ov5642_Sensor_Values.h`'s header guards are ineffective.  The bug is that `ov5642_Sensor_Values.h` should not be making any global definitions.  Header files should only *declare* things (with rare exceptions that you shouldn't worry about until you encounter them).

To fix the bug, change `ov5642_Sensor_Values.h` to declare `ov5642_1280x960_RAW` but not define it, like this:

```
#ifndef ARDUCAM_OV5642_SENSOR_VALUES_H_
#define ARDUCAM_OV5642_SENSOR_VALUES_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include "sensor_reg.h"

extern const struct sensor_reg ov5642_1280x960_RAW[];

#endif
```

and create a new file named `ov5642_Sensor_Values.c` that contains the initialized definition:

```
#include "ov5642_Sensor_Values.h"

extern const struct sensor_reg ov5642_1280x960_RAW[] =
{
    {0x3103,0x93},
    {0x3008,0x02},
    {0x3017,0x7f},
    .....
};
```

and add that file to your link.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone especially John, Zwoi. I was up against a deadline (this was inherited code) but was able to calm myself down enough to figure out what John was saying. I moved the struct definition into a c file and used an extern pointer in the header which is similar to zwoi's declaration. I am also relieved that  what I did matched zwoi's example (thank you so much!).

extern const struct sensor_reg * ov5642_1280x960_RAW;